# how to resolve exception on creating the Spring context?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, alfresco

i'm use sdk alfresco 4.0d ,eclipse ide juno ,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'encryptionKeysRegistry' defined in class path resource [alfresco/encryption-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionService' while setting bean property 'transactionService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionService' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.alfresco.util.BaseApplicationContextHelper.getApplicationContext(BaseApplicationContextHelper.java:67)
        at org.alfresco.util.ApplicationContextHelper.getApplicationContext(ApplicationContextHelper.java:46)
        at org.alfresco.sample.FirstFoundationClient.main(FirstFoundationClient.java:63)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionService' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        ... 27 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
        at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.determineDialect(DialectFactory.java:59)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:426)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2073)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1298)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        ... 44 more
```

i'm try to run firstFoundationClient but it have exception above

```
// locate the company home node
//
SearchService searchService = serviceRegistry.getSearchService();
StoreRef storeRef = new StoreRef(StoreRef.PROTOCOL_WORKSPACE, "SpacesStore");
ResultSet resultSet = searchService.query(storeRef, SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE,                   "PATH:\"/app:company_home\"");
NodeRef companyHome = resultSet.getNodeRef(0);
resultSet.close();
```

i want to use above code to search node in repository to show on alfresco page ,i'm  right?

sorry in my English

thank in advance

and this is my Hibernate configuration

```
#
# Hibernate configuration
#

# The Hibernate Dialect:
#    As of V3.1, the dialect is automatically detected.
#    It is still possible to set the dialect explicitly, for example:
#       hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect

hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=true
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
hibernate.max_fetch_depth=10
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.alfresco.repo.cache.InternalEhCacheManagerFactoryBean
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size=1
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=32
hibernate.connection.release_mode=auto
hibernate.connection.isolation=2

#hibernate.query.substitutions=
#hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys=false

# Oracle Schema Distinction:
#    See https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ETHREEOH-680
#    Metadata queries to Oracle have to be limited by schema name
#    when multiple instances of Alfresco are installed on an Oracle server.
#hibernate.default_schema=
```

Comment: Can we see your hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Comment: Please can you post your *full* stack trace? Normally exceptions indicating the Hibernate dialect should be explitly set would indiate a problem with your database settings, but without the full stack trace it is difficult to tell what the actual cause is.

Answer (score 2):

The very last line of the stack trace you posted might be the important one, especially this bit:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
```

You usually get this exception when the database connection is not properly setup. If the database connection fails, all the Spring beans that require the DB to be fully functional at startup time will fail to initialize, ultimately killing Alfresco before it's fully started.

Please verify that Alfresco can connect properly to the database and retry.